# jQuery Form Validation not throwing up any errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Okay, so I've been trying to get my form validation working, but I'm facing too many problems with it.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>JQuery Validation Engine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/template.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
        });

        /**
        *
        * @param {jqObject} the field where the validation applies
        * @param {Array[String]} validation rules for this field
        * @param {int} rule index
        * @param {Map} form options
        * @return an error string if validation failed
        */
        /*function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
            if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
                // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
                return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
            }
        }
        */
    </script>
</head>
    <div id="test" class="test" style="width:150px;">This is a div element</div>

<form id="formID" class="formular" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Required!
            </legend>
            <label>
                <span>Field is required : </span>
                <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req" id="req" />
            </label>
            <legend>
                Placeholder & required
            </legend>
            <label>
                <span>Field is required : </span>
                <input value="This is a placeholder" data-validation-placeholder="This is a placeholder" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="reqplaceholder" id="reqplaceholder" />
            </label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Source: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

I've been trying to get this thing working from past 1 hour.
I'm a newbie in jQuery so unable to find any problems here.

What am I doing wrong? Or what needs to be added for it to work correctly?

Here's a test url: http://www.vpsfort.net/test.html

Comment: What is it which this code is `not doing`?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined — is what I get. Your jquery link is not working

Comment: You should submit your form to get validation errors. Where is button/link to submit your form#formID?

Comment: Really your jQuery lib file is not loading in the page. That's the problem. Check the path

Comment: Hey @Unknown , added the submit button in the test URL..still doesn't do anything..

Comment: @Ankur jquery lib is not loading. check path once. http://www.vpsfort.net/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Your path of jquery file is showing like this http://www.vpsfort.net/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js. Is it the right path?? Its 404. That's why it shows jquery not defined

Comment: @PrasanthKC, Damn..was using 1.8.2 but mentioned 1.7.2.Silly me.Thanks for pointing out that glitch.Working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery path problem,JQuery is not loaded in your file,Kindly load before the all js file

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

How is the submit button?

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Validate &amp; Send the form!"/>
```

(Button from the Example)

And your Site has an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.
js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js <- doesn't exist on your Server!